# Does $\sum_{i\le k}\mathrm{frac}(n\alpha_i)<1$ hold infinitely often?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, diophantine-approximation

For each $t \in \mathbf{R}$, let $\mathrm{frac}(t)$ be its fractional part.

> **Question.** Fix reals $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k \in (0,1)$ such that $\sum_{i\le k}\alpha_i<1$. Do there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that
>   $$
> \sum_{i\le k}\mathrm{frac}(n\alpha_i)<1\,\,\,\,?
> $$

The answer is affirmative if $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k\}\setminus \mathbf{Q}$ is a set which is linearly independent over $\mathbf{Q}$ (applying the multidimensional equidistribution theorem). But I don't know in general.

Comment: Yes, because you can make $n\alpha_i$ very close to integers simultaneously, so at the very next step you'll get the fractional parts almost the same as the original numbers.

Comment: Yes by Poincaré recurrence.

Comment: @fedja Probably I am missing your point: also $0.99$ is close to an integer..

Comment: Yes, but $frac(0.99+0.23)$ is close to $0.23$ (next step means $n+1$ instead of $n$)